# Как пройти прокси аутентификацию в Google chrome

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

При запуске Chrome через Selenium появляется системной окошко, которое требует ввести логин и пароль для аутентификации. Вопрос - как его обойти?

Пытался самой Idea указывать параметры запуска - при запуске Idea висла и потом по тайм-ауту вылетала
Пытался сделать ярлык  хрома и запускать через него - Idea ругалась, что не может найти бинарник
и вариант при указании get(https://user:password@ya.ru) тоже не помог

Answer (score -1):

Указать прокси в настройках броузера: <kbd>Настройки</kbd> -> <kbd>Система</kbd> -> <kbd>Настройки прокси-сервера</kbd>